# ROC curves comparsion when dividing data into categories

Tags: statistical-significance, roc

I am dealing with a big set of observations ($>3000$).

There is a construced variable that predicts if an object should fall into category $A$ - high quality of life or $B$ - low quality, whereas we also have knowledge about the real situations. Constructing a ROC curve helped me see how well this variable fulfills its purpose.

But dealing with different problems while managing this data set, it is often divided into a few categories (e.g. number of children in the family). When I split data into these categories, the area under the ROC curve varies among categories. I'd like to find out if these differences are significant and I should consider that my variable is better/worse predictor for families with more kids or it's the same.

Since I couldn't find needed function in SPSS in which I mostly working right now, I have found James Hanley and Barbara McNeil's article (http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/Reprints/Method_of_Comparing_1983.pdf). Are there some faster ways then following their way? Are there some newer insights on this matter?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated, can you edit your question to summarise what the article you mention suggests? That way someone who reads your question can answer it, without first having to figure out what you are exactly asking. A link to the article would also be useful. As a hint, you can use google scholar to find recent papers that cite the Hanley & McNeil's paper. This should help answer the part of your question about newer insight on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed [here](http://fharrell.com/post/class-damage) and in the [Diagnosis chapter](http://fharrell.com/doc/bbr.pdf) of BBR, ROC curves are inefficient, non-enlightening, and inconsistent with optimal decision making.  Comparison of ROC curves and AUROC is statistically non-powerful.  And when you compare the c-index (AUROC) in different subsets, it is likely to vary for reasons you don't care so much about, such as the difficulty of the discrimination task increasing when you restricted the range of an important predictor.  Instead of the ROC method you'd be better served for doing likelihood ratio or Wald $\chi^2$ tests in the context of the full model, once you've precisely formed meaningful hypotheses you want to test.  You can also use the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ and measures of explained variation to describe which predictors are 'doing the main work' as outlined [here](http://www.fharrell.com/talk/memtab18).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I'll try different approaches. But I'll state my problem more straightforwardly, even if I acknowledge is not the best way to go: I have a neatly constructed predictor, which is just one varibale and not to be changed (at least for now). I wanted to confront it's prediction with real status - firstly with general population and then dividing into let's say 5 categories. Each time I get an acceptable area under the curve (from 0,6 to 0,8 in each category; decreasingly with the rise of the numer of category), but I'd like to know

Comment: if it is true that my predictor works worse for those record from categories from higher numbers.